# Orchard Element Editor

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I have a custom element which is a table .

on the `Editor` the administrator choose what datasource should be passed to that Element (E.g a list of people) .

whenever the page is reloaded or restarted , Orchard does not remember that the the element placed on the layout contains a data source of Persons .

how can i achieve this ? (assign data source to the element, another element with the same type should be able to get another data source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a similar scenario as implemented by the `Projection` element, which enables the user to select a Query as its data source. The `Projection` element stores the selected data source by its identifier in its `Data` dictionary. You need to do the same. For example, if you want to store the selected data source in a property of your Table element, that property implementation would look like this:

```
public string DataSourceId {
   get { return this.Retrieve<string>(x => x.DataSourceId); }
   set { this.Store(x => x.DataSourceId, value); }
}
```

The `Retrieve` and `Store` methods are extension methods on `IElement`, and simply store and read the values from a `Data` dictionary which gets serialized for you. That is key to persisting your custom element's properties.

Comment: This is exactly what i figure it out looking at some built-in elements .